# Overflow while shiffting C

Tags: c, sockets, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Hello i am trying to concatenate 2 `uint32_t` to make a 64 bit message to send throw a socket. But i get the following error
`warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow] uint64_t mensaje = (random_number << 32) | mensaje_temp;`
Here is some code sample:

```
void send_msg(int num, int connsocket){
    uint8_t largo = 6;
    uint8_t type = 11;
    uint16_t filler = 0;
    uint32_t random_number = num;
    uint16_t second_part = (type << 8) | largo;
    uint32_t mensaje_temp = (filler << 16) | second_part;
    uint64_t mensaje = (random_number << 32) | mensaje_temp;
    size_t msg_length = 8;
    char *new_msg = (char*)&mensaje;
}
```

I just did a similar thing to concatenate `uint8_t` types with a similar code and it worked, Any advice on how to manipulate safely this type of data would be great.

Comment: You need to explicitly convert to the wider type _before_ shifting left, e.g. `mensaje = (((uint64_t) random_number) << 32) | mensaje_temp;` Similarly. when going the other way, make sure to convert to the narrower type _after_ shifting right.

Comment: Thanks! it worked what do you mean by narrower type im not familiar with the concept :S

Comment: A type is narrower if it has fewer value bits, and wider if it has more.  That's really all there is to that.